# How to create a 3 columns fluid fixed fluid layout?

Tags: html, css

I'm looking for a 3 column css layout, with 1 fixed section at the middle and 2 fluid sidebar around it:

http://www.uploadup.com/di-UEFI.png

middle has 250px width (for example) and sidebars have (at minimum) 150px width. if browser width was longer than 550px (250+300), sidebars should have a longer width. (and middle always is 250px)

What is the CSS can do it? with compatibility in all browsers.

**note**: i saw [this page](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-38-fluid-fixed-fluid/), but i don't know how to change it for my wish

Comment: I take it "all browsers" includes IE7. Does it also include IE6?

Comment: yes, but i can use an other css file for ie6

Comment: I seldom say this, but you really should just learn CSS instead of asking people to do this for you.  The reason is, you will not understand how to modify the CSS when you need to.  CSS is something that will pay off if you spend the time to learn it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try to use `inline-block`s for it. They are used rather rarely, but sometimes they are pretty good for layouts.

So, look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/UUzE9/ — with `inline-block`s you can create layouts with any number of fixed and fluid columns. The algorithm:

1. At first, you add the padding equal to the sum of all the fixed columns to the wrapper. In your case — `250px`.
2. Then, you add `min-width` to the wrapper equal to the sum of all the fluid columns' min-width.
3. Then, you add `white-space: nowrap` to the wrapper, so the columns won't jump.
4. And then just add the all columns that you need.

If you need support for IE7 and lesser, there are some additional things to know except for common `inline-block` fix:

1. You must return `white-space: normal` to the inner child of a column, or the columns won't stay on one line.
2. There can appear a phantom scroll in IE, maybe there is a better way to remove it, but I just use `overflow: hidden` on some wrapper.

Enjoy :)

Comment: 20 minutes ago I didn't think this would work in IE6, but it does. This is perfect if the columns don't have to be equal height.

Comment: Yeah, however it's sad that you need extra wrappers and overflow:hidden just for IE.

Comment: I get white borders displayed between the divs. How can I avoid this? (can be reproduced by using TidyUp in fiddle and Run the code again)

Answer (score 4):

To make this work in IE6/7 without JavaScript, the easiest way to do this is with a `table`.

I know, I know. It's not *that* bad in this case, all considered.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/Q2Qxz/

Tested in IE6/7 + Chrome, and it will just work in all other modern browsers.

**HTML:**

```html
<table id="container" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td id="left">fluid</td>
        <td id="mid">fixed</td>
        <td id="right">fluid</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0
}
#container {
    border: 0;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%
}
#container td {
    vertical-align: top
}
#mid {
    width: 250px;
    background: #ccc
}
#left {
    background: #f0f
}
#right {
    background: #f0f
}
```

Comment: I can think of a way that will work in IE7, but *won't* work in IE6 that "uses `div`s". Do you want me to post it?

Comment: Oh, and one more question: do the columns have to be equal height?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use one of the ready templates out there,
You can start by three `div` floated left, the middle with width: 250px and the outside ones with
`min-width: 150px`
You might want to replace it with the `<section>` tag, just give it a `display: block`

Comment: and how to place them beside? width float and margin?

Comment: from there on, it depends on you. depends on the actual visual styles you wish to apply.

Comment: my problem is there (sorry for bad english) i don't know how can i place them. and what styles should i use.

Comment: Go for the table solution. No point in wasting too much time on things only developers care about (DIVs vs TABLEs).