# A center div of 960px wide, I want divs on the left and right hand sides to fill the remaining space equally on both sides

Tags: html, css

What is the best way ?

I had a look around and best I could find was specifying the left and right div widths.

Whereas I want the center div width specified, and the left and right to fit around that.

Comment: The accepted answer here is exactly what you need: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7699552/405015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you are going to be able to do it without using JavaScript.

Example using jQuery:

```
$('#div1, #div3').css({width: $(window).width()/2});
```