# How to implement a fluid-fixed-fluid three column layout with Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, multiple-columns

In one project I need to implement a 3-columns-layout with a fixed sized column in the middle and two further columns with a variable width (each `min = 100px` and `max = /100% - 500px) / 2`):

[image: 3-columns-layput]

(How) Can this be implemented on using Twitter Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that Bootstrap doesn't provide an instrument to implement such a mixed fixed-fluid layout. One has to use a workaroud like this (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7699552/how-to-create-a-3-columns-fluid-fixed-fluid-layout/7699778#7699778), see also http://jsfiddle.net/kizu/UUzE9/):

**CSS**

```
#main {
    min-width: 500px;
    padding: 0 500px 0 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.main-column {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}

#main-column-left {
    width: 50%;
    background: #00FFB4;
}
#main-column-middle {
    width: 500px;
    background: #434343;
}
#main-column-right {
    width: 50%;
    background: #FF9000;
}

.content {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="main-column" id="main-column-left"><div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div></div>
    <div class="main-column" id="main-column-middle"><div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div></div>
    <div class="main-column" id="main-column-right"><div class="content">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div></div>
</div>
```

But it's **not** a solution. So if someone knows a bootstrap conform way, please feel free to post it.